# Can we say "fulfill oneself"?

Tags: idiom-requests

Is it a correct way to say in English: "to fulfill oneself" or would there be a better way to express it in a few words? Thanks!

Comment: There is an expression  'a self-fulfilling prophecy' but I think the 'self' refers to a personification of the prophecy rather than refer to the person uttering it.

Comment: Could you give an example sentence for context?